# Java --> libGdx project --> Html --> gwt exception --> GWT reflection?

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx

### Edited #2

I compiled my libGDX project using `gradlew.bat html:dist` and got a dist folder with all my assets, html.index, and other files.

I put the dist folder in a zip and uploaded it to [itch.io](https://itch.io),

The game loads fine and everything seemed to be working as it should.

But the levels are unplayable. I get an error when trying to load the [Tiled Map](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps):

[image]

But it works fine as a executable .jar file and as an android app. The html version seems to have a problem loading objects from the tiled map.

**Update**

I think I need to use [reflection](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection#gwt), but I'm not sure how in this case.

Code I think is the problem:

```
for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(1).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {...}
```

Is this the right way to reflect this object, by just adding this to my  GdxDefinition.gwt.xml: ?

```
 <extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject" />
```

Also, this line in *.gwt.xml says: "URI not registered"

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
```

---

UPDATE

I just added the extended configuration property and it works! Despite the "URI not registered" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use [reflection](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection#gwt):

Just added this to my  GdxDefinition.gwt.xml:

```
 <extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Some minutes ago I successfully uploaded my libGDX game to itch.io. I would recommend you to upload your game as a HTML5 generated project. Make sure that you upload a ZIP with the `index.html` in the root path. Maybe check if it is possible to run your game locally/on a web server.

Consider posting your html/build.gradle file or the build output for further help.

Comment: I made a silly mistake but now it "works". Just that two new problems occurred.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit2**

Want to remove refresh button ??

Open your index.html and remove this line, it will remove your refresh button

```
<a class="superdev" href="javascript:%7B%20window.__gwt_bookmarklet_params%20%3D%20%7B'server_url'%3A'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2F'%7D%3B%20var%20s%20%3D%20document.createElement('script')%3B%20s.src%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fdev_mode_on.js'%3B%20void(document.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(s))%3B%7D">&#8635;</a>
```

Unable to load Tiled Map into GWT ?

you're using CSV, use Base64(uncompressed) as Tile Layer Format.

Comment: Thanks, but the game window still does not expand to the edges which is the main concern other than the bug with the gwt.

Comment: what is your GwtApplicationConfiguration width and height. I mostly use width 720 and height 480. check it in your into HtmlLauncher class. In your itch.io game page there is **Embed options** section having Viewport dimensions field put 740 as a width and 500 as height.

Comment: Oh my, I was changing that recently and forgot to change it back to my desired 800x480, it was left at half of that and thats why my game view is half the size... Anyway the tiled map error is what I can't grasp in any way still.

Comment: what is the Tile Layer Format for your .tmx file.??

Comment: One Tile layer, two object layers with only rectangles.

Comment: open your .tmx file in Tiled Map editor. Click on map menu of menubar and open Map Properties. There you find Tile Layer Format. what is the value of this property.

Comment: use Base64(uncompressed)

Comment: Now I need to change all my maps, but... Will that work on all platforms? Android, iOS, executable.jar & html?

Comment: Thanks! Does it affect the size of the files much? If it does I would need separate maps for android version.

Comment: yes size increased. you can keep separate map for other platforms.

Comment: could you update your answer with that since my quesiton is edited.

Comment: I run into an error while compiling for html I'm trying to sort that out. "Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133199/discussion-between-dushdushdush-and-abhishek-aryan).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1** Unable to upload on itch.io :

Just zip your dist folder so that you have dist.zip file for upload.

In your game page there is **Kind of project** choose menu. Select HTML not java applet from that menu.

In Uploads section by using **Upload files** button, upload your zipped file.
Wait for upload after that just save your game page and view.

Hopefully you got your game on your browser.

Thanks